# React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements)...; using fixed-data-table CDN

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a React app that is getting errors

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `BasicDataTableExample`.

and

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `BasicDataTableExample`.

I'm at the `Create your Columns` section of https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/getting-started.html

The difference is I'm using a cdn, and they use

```
const {Table, Column, Cell} = require('fixed-data-table');
```

instead.

I try unpacking like `const Table = FixedDataTable.Table;`, which seems to work when I went into debugger, but the app is broken. It looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
    <head>
        <title>data-table-basic</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/4.0.0-beta.3/react-router.min.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fixed-data-table/0.6.3/fixed-data-table.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fixed-data-table/0.6.3/fixed-data-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <head>

      
    <body>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/clock">clock</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/counter">counter</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/data-table-basic">data-table-basic</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/query-params-react-router">query-params-react-router</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/todo-list">todo-list</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="/validated-form">validated-form</a>



        <div id="entry"></div>
        <div id="code"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
var destination = document.querySelector("#entry");
            
const Table = FixedDataTable.Table;
const Column = FixedDataTable.Column;
const Cell = FixedDataTable.cell;


class BasicDataTableExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      myTableData: [
        {name: 'Rylan'},
        {name: 'Amelia'},
        {name: 'Estevan'},
        {name: 'Florence'},
        {name: 'Tressa'},
      ],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Table
        rowsCount={this.state.myTableData.length}
        rowHeight={50}
        headerHeight={50}
        width={1000}
        height={500}>
        <Column
          header={<Cell>Name</Cell>}
          cell={props => (
            <Cell {...props}>
              {this.state.myTableData[props.rowIndex].name}
            </Cell>
          )}
          width={200}
        />
      </Table>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <BasicDataTableExample/>
    </div>,
    destination
)

        </script>
    </body>
  
</html>
```

How do I make the `Table`, `Column`, and `Cell` show up correctly like they did using cdn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is likely that `Cell` is `undefined`, as you are trying to retrieve it as

```
const Cell = FixedDataTable.cell;
```

, while the property starts with an upper case `C`:

```
const Cell = FixedDataTable.Cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CDN then wrap your function into IIFE:

```
(function() {
    //your code will be executed after window load
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Timo is right. But instead of

```
const Table = FixedDataTable.Table;
const Column = FixedDataTable.Column;
const Cell = FixedDataTable.Cell;
```

you could destructure the components when importing the module using

```
import {Table, Column, Cell} from 'fixed-data-table';
```

*Less keystrokes.*

[MDN docs on import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)